# Sharepoint Oline - Refused to display 'https://xxx.sharepoint.com' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: iframe, sharepoint, office365, embed, sharepoint-online

I develop a SharePoint-hosted app. I have a web part where I try to show the document library of the sharepoint host.

To do this, I set the iframe src based on the current user. But when I set the url I have the error:

> Refused to display 'https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/Documentos%20compartidos/folder1/folder2' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

I try to set in *AppManifest.xml*

```
<AppPrincipal>
   <Internal AllowedRemoteHostUrl="https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx"/>
</AppPrincipal>
```

Also, on the head of the page of web part, I add:

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="allow">
   ...
</head>
```

And get the error:

> X-Frame-Options may only be set via an HTTP header sent along with a document. It may not be set inside .

How do I resolve the error? Are there other options to show document library on a web part?

Answer (score 0):

After search and read some blogs I discover that it is imposible do that i want because of security restrictions.

My solution:

1. Create a iframe in a edit content, in the same page where I add the web part
2. Send the url from the web part, using `parent.postMessage( { url: url }, '*');`, and change the iframe's url with jQuery from the editcontent